# Cant create a vector with a specified size

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a vector with a specific size, of 255 (max)..
It doesnt work for me, like I see in examples over the internet...

I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2012...

I have the current code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int MAX = 255;

class test
{
vector <string> Name(MAX);
};

int main()
{
system("PAUSE");
}
```

It gives me 2 errors :

`Error  1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'MAX'`

`2   IntelliSense: variable "MAX" is not a type name`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In C++11, you can use `vector<string> Name{MAX};` However, this only works in this case for vector because the initializer constructor is not compatible with a type of `int` for `std::string`. Put more clearly, with a type of `int` instead of `std::string`, the vector will contain 1 element - 256 - rather than 256 default-initialized elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not valid syntax for a class declaration. Try:

```
class test
{
   vector <string> Name;
   test() : Name(MAX) {}
};
```

You can write `vector <string> Name(MAX);` when you create a variable (in your case, you're declaring a member). For example:

```
int main()
{
   vector <string> Name(MAX);
}
```

would be perfectly valid.

Comment: Can you have a space after `vector`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialize a data member inside the class declaration like this. Use the member initialization list in your constructor of the class to initialize `vector<string> Name`.

```
test::test
:Name(MAX)
{
  //
}
```

Your main would be like this.

```
test t1 ;
```

It would automatically call the constructor and all the fields of `t1` would be created, including `vector<string> Name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass arguments to the `std::vector` constructor int the class declaration.  You should put that in the constructor for your class, like this, which utilizes does it via an initializer list:

```
class test
{
    std::vector<std::string> Name;

    public:

    test():
        Name(MAX)
    {
    }
};
```